# How to fix error referencing jquery from nested web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm getting the error shown below from jquery when I try to used from a web page in a nested directory.  How do I prevent this error.

This is what the directory structure looks like.  (Using `<script src="/fhir-to-omop/site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` from the circled index page works)

[image]

I've tried referencing jquery using each of these from the circled StartHere.html page:

```
    <script src="../../../../site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR

```
    <script src="/fhir-to-omop/site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the error I'm getting

[image]

```
jquery.min.js:5          GET https://nachc-cad.github.io/fhir-to-omop/pages/navbar/getting-started/start-here/site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js?_=1646571234525 404
```

---

EDIT: Per the question in the comments: I am loading JQuery twice as shown below.

In the main file:

```
<html>
    
    <head>
        <!-- favicon link -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
        <!-- include lib code -->
        <script src="../../../../site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="headerInclude"></div>
        <script>$("#headerInclude").load("/fhir-to-omop/header.html");</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid main-container">

            <!-- navbar -->
            <div id="navbarInclude"></div>
            <script>$("#navbarInclude").load("/fhir-to-omop/navbar.html");</script>
        ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then this exists at the top of the loaded navbar.html:

```
<!-- navbar -->
<head>
    <!-- include lib code -->
    <script src="site_libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: The error in the screen came from the Ajax request (called by jQuery) that returns HTML instead of JSON. The jQuery loaded successfully that's why you get jQuery Stack Trace. Maybe you're trying to load two versions of jQuery.

Comment: I am loading JQuery twice, but it is the same version.

Comment: Any reason why you load it twice? You just probably use $.getScript('jQuery') but the URL is wrong so it return 404 but you try to execute HTML.

Comment: When I was first setting things up I got exceptions if I did not include jQuery the second time.  I'll revisit this and post an edit describing the behavior when I get a chance.